# What is the meaning of the "less than" or "<" sign in mongoimport?

Tags: mongodb

What exactly does the 'less than' or '<' sign do in turns of mongoimport.  For example, what is the difference between:

1. mongoimport -d test -c work -f information.json
2. mongoimport -d test -c work < information.json

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not mongo. That's your shell, `<` is input redirection.

```
echo foo > somefile.txt
         ^---  redirect output: write "foo" to somefile.txt

someapp < somefile.txt
        ^--- send file's contents to 'someapp' as input.


someapp | otherapp
     take output from "someapp" and feed to "otherapp" as input.
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation; I really appreciate it.  It comes to show how little I know about the shell.